# SVN load dump to exact folder

Tags: svn, version-control, svndump

Have a standard subversion layout with one branch :

**Repo_1**

`repo_root
  |-branches
   |-branch_one
  |-tags
  |-trunk`

And a second repository,
**Repo_2**

`repo_root
  |-branches
  |-tags
  |-trunk
   |-folder1`

I want to export **Repo_2/trunk/folder1** content to **Repo_1/branches/branch_one/folder1**

I'm making the folder dump : 
`svnrdump dump svn://mysvnserver/Repo_2/trunk/folder1 > folder1.dump`

Then loading it to my **Repo_1** : 
`svnadmin load Repo_1 --parent-dir branches/branch_one < folder1.dump`

And getting the following **Repo_1** structure :

`repo_root
  |-branches
   |-branch_one
    |-trunk
     |-folder1
  |-tags
  |-trunk`

getting the trunk folder I don't need there. Is there any way to plug in my **"folder1"** directly to **"branch_one"** ?

Comment: Why not `svn mv && svn rm` after load into repository?

Answer (score 4):

Re-read **carefully and fully** [Filtering Repository History](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering) in SVN Book, pay *special* attention on warnings

You forgot, that dump-file holds all relative paths for included in dump nodes inside file and `--parent-dir` change only starting mount-point of mentioned in dump nodes, not relative location

> Each of your dump files will create a valid repository, but will preserve the paths exactly as they were in the original repository. This means that even though you would have a repository solely for your calc project, that repository would still have a top-level directory named calc. If you want your trunk, tags, and branches directories to live in the root of your repository, you might wish to edit your dump files, tweaking the `Node-path` and `Node-copyfrom-path` headers so that they no longer have that first calc/ path component

From my own experience I prefer **always** filter dumps with `svndumpfilter include`, even if dump was created with svnrdump for only part of repo-tree: it produce less (0) errors or `svnadmin load`. For example, moving remote `REPO/trunk/lib` to the same path on local repository (there default repository-tree already exist) implies to me

```
>svnrdump dump URL/trunk/lib > full.dmp
>svndumpfilter include --pattern "*lib*" --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs < full.dmp > filtered3.dmp
```

<sup>(`include --pattern` just because plain `include lib` produced worse result, but it can be hands-related only problem)</sup>

and *this* filtered dump can be easy loaded

```
>svnadmin load Repo --parent-dir / < filtered3.dmp
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 1
     * adding path : trunk/lib ... done.
     * adding path : trunk/lib/lib01.txt ... done.

------- Committed new rev 2 (loaded from original rev 1) >>>
```

whereas "dumb" dump

`>svnrdump dump URL/trunk/lib > dump.dmp`

give error on load-attempt

```
>svnadmin load repo2 < dump.dmp
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 1
     * adding path : trunk ...svnadmin: E160020: File already exists: filesystem 'bcf62090-928b-9f49-8008-455204e6d81f', transaction '1-1', path '/trunk'
```